# Выборка по времени в sqllite3

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сменить настройку часового пояса?
запрос `SELECT datetime()` возвращает `2017-05-30 10:15:54`, хотя в моем часовом поясе `2017-05-30 15:15:54`
И как сделать выборку по времени, например в таблице есть даты+время

```
2017-05-31 13:50:00
2017-05-31 12:15:00
2017-05-31 10:40:00
2017-05-31 09:05:00
2017-05-31 07:30:00
```

Нужно выбрать все, что входит в `sysdate + 2 часа` (+4, +6).

Comment: Эммм... `SELECT datetime('now', 'localtime');` ?

Comment: @Akina оо, мерси) а как к этой дате добавить\вычесть 2 часа? SELECT datetime('now', 'localtime')-2/24 возвращает не то

Comment: Вопрос решен, нагуглил SELECT datetime('now', 'localtime', '+2 hour').
@Akina вам спасибо за наводку)